# Git - How can I use a specific remote branch as the upstream source for a repository?

Tags: git, workflow, branching-and-merging

Perhaps I'm thinking of a bad workflow, but here we go. I have a project that I would like to use as the base for other projects, since they all keep the same structure and share common classes. Such base project is stored in its own Git repository (let's call it **MyBaseRepo**), where two branches exist:

- **master**, containing a very stripped down version of the project.
- **mybranch**, containing everything included in master, plus more specific classes.

What I would like to do is the following:

- Create a new project, e.g. **MyNewProject**, cloning one of the two branches from **MyBaseRepo**.
- Create a new **MyNewProjectRepo** Git repository as the origin for the new project.
- Push/pull all changes related to the implementation of **MyNewProject** to **MyNewProjectRepo**.
- When **MyBaseRepo** gets updated, fetch the changes from the appropriate branch.

In short, I would like to put in place some sort of "repository inheritance", so that when base classes change, the child project can get the updates.

So far I can almost do the above by fetching **MyBaseRepo** when needed and then merging the appropriate **MyBaseRepo/branch** with **MyNewProject** master (or whatever **MyNewProject** branch). Is this the proper way of doing it, or am I making my life more complicated than it should be? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you described the problem (except the two branches part), you can go with [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). With it, every revision of your project will be bound to a specific revision of the submodule.

If you really need those two branches of `MyBaseRepo`, I would do this way:

- Initialize an empty repo:

`$ git init`

- Do a commit to initialize `master`
- Add the remote MyBaseRepo to the new repo:

`$ git remote add MyBaseRepo the_repo_location`
`$ git fetch MyBaseRepo`

- Then, when needed, merge:

`$ git merge MyBaseRepo/master`

or

`$ git merge MyBaseRepo/mybranch`.

But I would go with submodules. It's a "cleaner" solution - instead of merging from a remote branch, you'll only need to update the submodules.

Comment: I thought about submodules, but they would not do, because every subproject is practically a copy of the base project with some added files. The base project is the skeleton for other projects, thus directory tree, file names and so on have to be kept. It's not just a matter of including some files stored in a subfolder. Thanks anyway for your suggestions.